# A day and number of days ahead is given. return the day of week for number of days ahead

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a piece of code where a day and a number of days ahead is given - for example, (Monday, 3).

This should return back "Thursday" as 3 days from Monday is Thursday.

Here is what i have done. The issue with this is, If asked for (Thursdays,5) or (Wednesday,7) or (Friday, 2) it wont be able to return anything.

As you can see I am playing around with the index of the array to get the results. I am not sure how i need to modify the code to get, for example the day 10 days from Friday.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Day = "Friday";
            int ahead = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(FindDay(Day, ahead));
        }
        public static string FindDay(string dayGiven, int daysAhead) 
        {
            string[] week = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };
            int indexOfDayGiven = 0;
            string ans = "";
            foreach (string day in week)
            {
                if (day == dayGiven)
                {
                    indexOfDayGiven = Array.IndexOf(week, dayGiven);

                }
                
            }
            foreach(string day in week)
        
            {
                if (Array.IndexOf(week, day) ==indexOfDayGiven + daysAhead)
                {
                    ans = day;
                }
            }
            return ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: indexof + days modulo 7 ?

Comment: Mind, there is [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netcore-3.1) Enumeration which you may want to utilize for this? Another point: If `daysAhead` is expected to have positive values, only then you should guard against negative values (don't trust user input).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation which is `%` in c#.
something like this:

```
var ind = (indexOfDayGiven + daysAhead) % 7;
```

Comment: use `indexOfDayGiven = Array.IndexOf(week)` without `dayGiven`

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can use the modulus operator (which returns the remainder after division) to get a value that is within the array. So if you have `Friday` (`5`) and want to find out which day is `4` days away, we would add the two together and then take the modulus of the number of items in the array (`5 + 4 = 9; 9 % 7 = 2;`), or in one line: `((5 + 4) % 7) = 2`, and that is the index of our result:

```
int result = week[(Array.IndexOf(week, "Friday") + 4) % 7];
```

We can also make use of the `DayOfWeek` enum instead of creating an array of day names. This allows us to do a case-insensitive parsing of the input day string to get the enum value. The nice thing about this is that the enum contains both the `Name` and the `Index` in one object, so we don't have to lookup indexes - we can just cast to an `int`, do our math, and then cast the result back to a `DayOfWeek` and get the string result:

```
public static string FindDay(string dayGiven, int daysAhead)
{
    DayOfWeek startDay;

    if (!Enum.TryParse(dayGiven, true, out startDay))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"'{dayGiven}' is not a valid day.");
    }

    return ((DayOfWeek) (((int) startDay + daysAhead) % 7)).ToString();            
}
```

Comment: I'd actually recommend to return a `DayOfWeek` Value, which can be localized as seen fit by whoever calls the method (see my answer). I do realize, question also was english, only. Just for anyone's info.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make use of the [`DayOfWeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netcore-3.1) Enumeration like in the following example. The way to find the day stays the same as in the comments and other answers: Use the [(Integer) remainder operator '%'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-).

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 8;
        for ( int startDay = 0; startDay < 7 ; startDay++)
           Console.WriteLine("{0} days from {1} is {2}", n, GetDayName((DayOfWeek)startDay), GetDayName(GetDaysAhead((DayOfWeek)startDay, n)));
    }
    
    public static string GetDayName( DayOfWeek day )
    {
        return DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetDayName(day);
    }
    
    public static DayOfWeek GetDaysAhead(DayOfWeek start, int daysAhead)
    {
        if ( daysAhead < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(daysAhead));
        if ( daysAhead == 0 ) return start;
        return (DayOfWeek) (( (int)start + daysAhead ) % 7);
    }
}
```

`DayOfWeek` comes as Property of `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`. It isn't localized itself, but you can easily get localized strings as shown above.